# tabbar-mode brings editing to a crawling halt

Tags: emacs

I today tried tabbar-mode, both version 2.0.1 obtainable via the marmelade elpa repository, and version 2.0 from [dholms github repository](https://github.com/dholm/tabbar). When tabbar-mode is activated, keystrokes are lagging noticably (I'd say >1s).

I'm using emacs-24 as long running daemon, with cedet, gnus, erc active, with 2-3 clients showing ~7 Frames. The OS is linux, the windowmanager awesome.

Can you provide any hints what might be responsible, where to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple; `tabbar` uses three icons to the left of the tabbar; glancing over the code I noticed that it meddles with transparency issues -- that raised a red flag.
Setting

```
(setq tabbar-use-images nil)
```

before activating `tabbar-mode` replaces the icons with text - voila, everything is smooth again.