# tabbar alternative for emacs 24

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Unfortunately tabbar-mode makes emacs24 be extremely slow, especially when using smooth-scrolling. Does anybody know an alternative with similar effect as tabbar?

Comment: You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug`, since such slowness should not occur.

Comment: Yet another question closed for no good reason. I have the same problem, as do others (google "emacs tabbar slow"), and am interested in answers. How is the question "not constructive"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8617726/1806019, `(setq 'tabbar-use-images nil)`