# Aquamacs 2.4 -- subdirs.el -- How to exclude a path from loading

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am setting up Aquamacs 2.4 to be used on at least three different computers and I'm uncertain how best to go about excluding a path (e.g., `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/tabbar`)  from `subdirs.el` located within `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources`:

```
(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
    (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

And, another subdirs.el located within `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp`:

```
;; In load-path, after this directory should comecertain of its subdirectories.  Here we specify them.
    (normal-top-level-add-to-load-path '("url" "textmodes" "progmodes" "play" "org" "nxml" "net" "mh-e" "mail" "language" "international" "gnus" "eshell" "erc" "emulation" "emacs-lisp" "contrib" "cedet" "calendar" "calc" "aquamacs"  "obsolete"))
```

---

I spent several hours trouble-shooting and ultimately customizing `aquamacs-tabbar.el` within `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/tabbar`.  After finally figuring out what was happening, I had two obvious choices -- (1) hard-code `aquamacs-tabbar.el` by striking out the relevant portions that were **overriding** `customizations.el`; or, (2) hard-code all of my customizations directly into `aquamacs-tabbar.el`.  So now I have a hard-coded customized `aquamacs-tabbar.el` (hidden within the application package) -- I'd like to copy it over to a more user-friendly script loading directory `/Users/HOME/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs` so that I can use it there, and also synchronize that directory and all sub-directories with my other three computers.

I'd like to leave as much of the application intact as possible, but I really don't want to be synchronizing the application itself to multiple computers on an ongoing basis.

Maybe the solution is to just strip the guts out of Aquamacs 2.4, and synchronize the skeleton to all of my computers, and then place the stripped guts within  `/Users/HOME/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs`.  Then I can synchronize the latter with my other computers to my hearts content.

I'm sure that customizing `aquamacs-tabbar.el` is just the first of many scripts (hidden within the application package) that will need to be tweaked.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You sound like you're outgrowing aquamacs.  Can you explain what advantage aquamacs has over plain GNU Emacs?

Comment: WOW!  I had no idea another version of Emacs runs on OSX - - that would be awesome if I'm not restricted and dealing with the scenario described in this thread.  I'll start Googling now for an alternative . . . .  If you have a link to a version or documentation describing how to use an unrestricted version that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay -- I'm on it:  http://emacsformacosx.com/builds  If it works, the only important configuration will be to enable the latex build and jump to pdf that is built into the Aquamacs version, and the spell check.

Comment: Tabbar is not working in the new version [24.3 (9.0)] -- I've submitted an issue.  I found a solution for the slow-down caused by tabbar with Emacs 24 -- and I'll provide that to the author also.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520531/tabbar-mode-brings-editing-to-a-crawling-halt.  I like tabs, so I'm probably going to make due with Aquamacs for now.

Comment: In hindsight, I now have to admit that `event_jr` hit the nail on the head.  It's been quite a learning curve, which is still ongoing, but the comments of ` event_jr` have finally sunken in.  Thank you . . . advice usually takes an appreciable period of time to sink in.  I'll eventually update my answer with a more detailed solution for taking complete control over customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ideas regarding how to customize the paths for all emacs-related files during the build process (to have everything under the same roof), please refer to:

[OSX -- configuring Emacs to use NSSpellChecker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265742/osx-configuring-emacs-to-use-nsspellchecker/16444817#16444817)