# OSX -- configuring Emacs to use NSSpellChecker

Tags: emacs

I'm having trouble reverse-engineering Aquamacs to extract the usage / functionality of NSSpellChecker.  I would like to incorporate that use / functionality into a bare-bones build of Emacs from source.  I've located the seemingly relevant files -- `ns-win.el`; `flyspell.el`; and `ispell.el` -- however, simply replacing those files from Aquamacs to Emacs does not enable the pop-up menu for running the spell-checker that is native to OSX.  I'm missing one or more pieces to the puzzle -- I've opened all the Aquamacs *.gz files and searched for a few keywords within all of those files, but I haven't found any other files that look like they have something to do with this functionality.  The functionality is enabled by Aquamacs `before` its site-start.el is initiated.

I've learned how to build Emacs from source using the tarball, and also by using bzr.  If anyone knows how to configure NSSpellChecker during the build process, that would be great.

There is nothing I have found on the internet that remotely describes how to do this.

The spell check function of Aspell reminds me of what life was like back in the late-80's.  I've grown fond of the pop-up menu with buttons to select the spell-checking options.

Here is the link to an explanation for building Aquamacs, and looking into the build script is next on my to-do list:

http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BuildingAquamacs

Edit 1:  The build scripts have a little more to say about NSSpellChecker, so additional files that need to be looked at include:  `nsterm.m` and `nsfns.m`.  I don't think `aquamacs-menu.el` or `osxkeys.el` are necessary, because those load after site-start.el.  It's looking more and more like NSSpellChecker is hard-coded into the application executable during the build process, in conjunction with the files mentioned above.

Edit 2:  Yep, that was the missing piece of the puzzle.  The executable of Aquamacs within the application package (i.e., `... Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs`) contains the hard-coded magic for NSSpellChecker in conjunction with the Aquamacs modified versions of `ns-win.el`; `flyspell.el`; and `ispell.el`.

Edit 3:  At this point, one option would be to modify the build script for Aquamacs and related files used in the build process in order to build a custom application.  Alternatively, creating a hybrid is also possible, but comes with its own problems because the Aquamacs executable is hard-coded with specialties such as `one-frame-one-buffer-mode` when opening a file from Finder.app; `switch-to-buffer-in-tab` when opening a file from Finder.app; `ns-application-activated` that needs to be set to ignore; including the version id inside the init.el file to properly quiet the error message; easy-menu options that are geared towards Aquamacs for saving options; and a few other issues that are readily apparent.  In short, a hybrid is doable, but a pain in the neck.  I do have a hybrid working, but I'm sure I'll have to do more tweaking as I find more Aquamacs customizations (created by the executable) that need to be dealt with.  It is too early for me to post any type of an answer.  The build script modification appears to be the best solution, but would require a lot of time to modify it properly in order to create a custom build that isolates the NSSpellChecker feature.

Edit 4:  I have a working version with NSSpellChecker that is the executable of a custom build of Aquamacs24 (omitting almost everything Aquamacs except for the spellchecker), and the emacs-trunk most recent build of Emacs24 (nightly build).  I'm waiting on receiving some technical support to use the terminal for downloading the latest branch of Aquamacs24 with git because I'm having some issues duplicating the ZIP version with the terminal.  This is pretty detailed and I'd like to simplify the process before posting an answer, and I want to test it out thoroughly beforehand.

[image: NSSpellChecker]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://lawlist.com/images/spellchecker.png))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The patches (referred to below) were created by @lawlist from select portions of the Aquamacs:

https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs

To enable native spellchecking on OSX in the vanilla/generic version of Emacs, it is necessary to patch the C-source-code prior building, and a few lisp files also need to be modified.  The patch is too big to post in an answer on stackexchange.com.

The following procedure assumes the necessary tools have already been installed on OSX to build and patch, etc. -- e.g., git, recent versions of `automake` and `autoconf`, xcode, etc.

---

**EMACS-25 BRANCH -- NOVEMBER 1, 2016**:

The following patch and *minimal* testing was performed on the **emacs-25 branch** built `--with-ns` as of commit dated November 1, 2016:  `5043e0a7e06dbf6507a59736e55bdde69d9a2a4e`

From a terminal, type:  `git clone -b emacs-25 git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git`

Visit:  https://gist.github.com/lawlist/dfc75240cc06c66f19f48eaa3e570d7c

Click the "**Download ZIP**" button, and save the zipped patch file somewhere on your computer.

Extract the **ZIP** archive you just downloaded and save `nsspellchecker_emacs25.diff` to the `.../emacs` root source-code directory that was cloned in the first step above.

From a terminal, `cd` over to the root `.../emacs` source-code directory.

;; The patch may become outdated, so this example includes a hard reset to go back to November 1, 2016.  [Certain bug fixes are still being made to Emacs 25 by the development team, which may cause the patch to become outdated.]

From a terminal, type:  `git reset --hard 5043e0a7e06dbf6507a59736e55bdde69d9a2a4e`

;; After performing a hard reset successfully, the message in the terminal will say:  "**HEAD is now at 5043e0a Fix documentation for 'eudc-options-file'**"

From a terminal, type:  `git apply nsspellchecker_emacs25.diff`

From a terminal, type:  `./autogen.sh`

From a terminal, type:  `./configure --with-ns`

From a terminal, type:  `make`

From a terminal, type:  `make install`

;; With Finder.app, navigate over to `.../emacs/nextstep` and try out your new Emacs.app

;; Open your new Emacs.app and type `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'flyspell) RET`

;; In a `*scratch*` buffer, type something spelled correctly and something spelled wrong.

;; Type:  `M-x ns-start-spellchecker` or `M-x ispell-buffer`

;; Play a little with the pop-up spellchecker and have fun.

;; Custom words are saved to:  `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`

---

**Previous answer that applies to the `master` branch as of May 29, 2016**:

The following patch and *minimal* testing was performed on **master branch** built `--with-ns` as of commit dated May 29, 2016:  `76fb19b359dec8556dc66dbac3ad3d333feea3c3`

From a terminal, type:  `git clone -b master git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git`

Visit:  https://gist.github.com/lawlist/6a9b281870fcc114ad3c6c1dca121f95

Click the "**Download ZIP**" button, and save the zipped patch file somewhere on your computer.

Extract the **ZIP** archive you just downloaded and save `nsspellchecker.diff` to the `.../emacs` root source-code directory that was cloned in the first step above.

From a terminal, `cd` over to the root `.../emacs` source-code directory.

;; The patch will soon become outdated, so this example includes a hard reset to go back to May 29, 2016.  [I will not be updating/maintaining the patch as Emacs **master branch** changes several times each day.]

From a terminal, type:  `git reset --hard 76fb19b359dec8556dc66dbac3ad3d333feea3c3`

;; After performing a hard reset successfully, the message in the terminal will say:  "**HEAD is now at 76fb19b * lisp/wid-edit.el (link): Remove :follow-link property (bug#22434)**"

From a terminal, type:  `git apply nsspellchecker.diff`

Comment: Is there any effort to make this available as a configuration option for the mainline Emacs?

Comment: @tripleee -- I'm not certain whether Richard M. Stallman, John Wiegley or Eli Zaretskii would be interested in having a feature that is OSX specific.  My guess is that they would not, however, John uses OSX -- so he *might* be interested.  RMS would undoubtedly insist upon having David Swelt (for the C-source code modifications) and Nathaniel Cunningham (ispell.el/flyspell.el), and others, sign off on paperwork to have their contributions become an official part of Emacs, which they may not be willing to do even though the license is GNU.  Also, "Aquamacs" accepts donations . . .